# SharePoint 2010 & Powershell

Tags: powershell, administration

I want to learn Powershell with SharePoint 2010, please let me know if there are resources available on the Internet.

Comment: This type of questions with open answers should be marked as commnity content :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a great blog site for real world scripts located at http://get-spscripts.com/ I have used a lot of info here as a base for my learning PowerShell for SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 0):

What is it you want to learn?  The Administration portion of SharePoint 2010 or are you trying to do set up sites or automate many of the creation and deployment functions with PowerShell?

Anders is right, this is a very open ended question and could go many ways depending on what you are looking to accomplish.